# Try Catch Extension For the Main Method?

Tags: c#, exception, logging, try-catch

I have this Logger class:

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static void LogError(Exception e)
    {

    }

    public static void TryCatchLogError<T>(this T item, Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I can do this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void GetBreakDownMachine()=>  this.TryCatchLogError(() =>
    {
        {
            //my code
        }
    });
}
```

But cannot do the same inside my static main class

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()=>  this.TryCatchLogError(() =>
    {
        {
            //my code
        }
    });
}
```

How can i make use of the Logger extension class for the above Static method?

Comment: "item" parameter is the object from which the exception is thrown. I removed it's usage here since it had sensitive content .

Comment: `[STAThread]
        static void Main() => Logger.TryCatchLogError<Program>(null, () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bob");
        });` _You can't use `this.` in the context of a `static` method since it makes no sense - there is no instance to speak of._

Comment: How silly ,i missed to remove static for the class. My bad again. i've tried your suggestion previously too but as said missed making class non-static. It works now, Also now i understand what @theGeneral answer . thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make the main method of a class an [Expression Bodied Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members), like so (at least to a console app)

```
private static void Main(string[] args) => Console.WriteLine("asdasd");
```

However, this is fairly ugly and i would never do it personally. Also the whole *Expression try catch* thing doesn't sit well with me either. Its just an extra call to the stack to sully up your stack trace and worst of all you aren't dealing with the exception and just using a blanket catchall.

I would reconsider both approaches

If you really want to go down this rabbit hole you need to pass in T Item

```
public static void TryCatchLogError<T>(this T item, Action action)
{
   try
   {
      action();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     // LogError(ex);
   }
}

private static void Main() => 
   TryCatchLogError("asd",  // <== here needs to be T Item
      () =>
         {
            Console.WriteLine("asdasd");
         });
```

Comment: i get what you're saying but i need to use the Logger extension mentioned in the post for strategical purpose (we are experimenting few design principles) .

Comment: your solution works but suggestion from @mjwills in the comments is a bit apt for my case. But if my class has to stay static for some reason your solution is the way to go. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs an 'item' but Main does not provide it. There is no 'this' in Main.

Comment: Understood, Is there a way i could make use of my Logger extension for the Main Method?.

Comment: It needs an Item. If you have it, you can call myItem.TryCatchLogError(..) instead of this.TruCatchLogError.